# ProgressBar on top of FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a strange situation. I'm using NexPlayer to render streaming video in openGL mode. On top of the rendering area for the streaming video (a framelayout), I display a ProgressBar in indeterminate mode whenever the videoplayer is buffering - comparable to what the youtube app does.

This works fine up to the point where the player stops buffering and I try to remove the progressbar from the screen. The progressbar stops animating, but it remains on screen, as if it were a watermark on the video.
The way I try to remove it is by changing the visibility of the progressbar; I've tried both View.INVISIBLE and View.GONE but neither works.
I also tried wrapping the progressbar in another layout and changing the visibility of that container, but to no avail.

I did notice that when I rotate the device, the progressbar disappears.

Below is the xml layout for the player activity. The surfaceview in there is only used in case the device does not support OpenGL 2.0.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get rid of this ProgressBar?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/gl_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
</FrameLayout>

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
</SurfaceView>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/controlContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#aa000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonPausePlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_play_pause"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_stop" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: the code that changes the visibility of the view:

```
@Override
public void onBuffering(int progress_in_percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Buffering " + progress_in_percent + " %");
}

@Override
public void onBufferingBegin() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Buffering begin");
     loadingContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onBufferingEnd() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Buffering end");
    loadingContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

These methods get called from within the NexPlayer framework. I'm sure they do get called since I get the output in the logs.

Comment: Could you post the code you use to show and try to hide the progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I figured it out. The callback I was getting from the NexPlayer framework wasn't on the UI thread. Oddly enough, this did not cause any stacktraces in the log so I didn't notice this until I attached my debugger and added a breakpoint that suspends on any exception.

I fixed this by creating runnables that do exactly the same thing as the code above and posting them to my handler.

(It still does beat me why the ProgressBar showed up in the first place though, since it was also being made visible on the wrong thread :/)